# How to control frame height and width in chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-frame

I am working with chrome extension.

Here in button click i required to open a menu.
When toolbar loaded in memory it make a space for menu item I want to remove it in page load.

[image: Before Button click] 
[image: After Click button]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no visible elements taller than 100px on the popup page:

```
document.body.style.height="100px";
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height="100px";
```

If this doesn't work then some element is still considered visible (Chrome is picky about this).

The best way to figure it out would be to use the popup inspector.

- Right click on the popup icon, select "inspect pop-up".
- Set height for `<html>` and `<body>` elements
- Set height for your container div
- Play with `height`, `overflow:hidden`, `float:left`, `display:none` on a container div and its children until popup shrinks to the required height